# Why/how can certification fail on AUTH_URL/auth/tokens "No such file" error?

Tags: python, ssl, openstack, openstack-shade

I am following these [instructions](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214836997-How-to-launch-and-delete-OpenStack-instances-using-Python-and-Shade); but when I run the given sample

```
from shade import *

simple_logging(debug=True)
conn = openstack_cloud(cloud='myopenstack')
images = conn.list_images()
for image in images:
  print(image)
```

I get:

> keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.SSLError: SSL exception connecting to MY-URL/auth/tokens: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

I then remembered that the folks providing this cloud to us told us to use the "--insecure" parameter when using the python openstack client. I did some more searching, and changed one line

```
conn = openstack_cloud(cloud='myopenstack', verify='False')
```

Now I get:

> keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.SSLError: SSL exception connecting to MY-AUTH_URL/auth/tokens: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

But now I am kinda lost - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a solution to make the call with `verify` work out; but the people providing this openstack instance provided a special certificate to me; and with that; I do:

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = './special.pem'
```

And everything works!

( so the answer is to workaround the certificate validation by fixing the certificate ;-)